# Mongo JPA: Multiple Group Operations

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

Given the following dataset:

| category | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fruit | 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| fruit | 2023-01-02 | 2 |
| meat | 2023-01-03 | 3 |
| nuts | 2023-01-04 | 4 |
| nuts | 2023-01-05 | 5 |
| nuts | 2023-01-06 | 6 |

Is it possible to do a multi-group aggregation in Mongo JPA that yields:

- One row per category
- Count of rows in that category
- Amount on `max(date)`

| category | count | last_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fruit | 2 | 2 |
| meat | 1 | 3 |
| nuts | 3 | 6 |

This should be possible in a relational database with some SQL grouping and possibly sub-queries but seems incredibly difficult to achieve in Mongo. I could get get the row count in one aggregation but seems like I would need multiple operations to achieve what I need.

Comment: I think it might be possible, if you can add some sample input documents and expected documents, we can try it out.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor added some example data as requested

Comment: Added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was genuinely surprisingly difficult to achieve. Charchit pointed me in the right direction but to get to the exact response I wanted required so much more effort.

Explanation of stages required:

- `$group`: group the collection by `category` and obtain the `$sum`  and the `$max($date)` of each category
- `$lookup`: join the collection with itself to obtain the `amount` at the
  `maxDate`
- the `$lookup` `pipeline` is required because a multi-field match needs to be performed ensuring the match is for the `maxDate` only for that given `category`
- the `$lookup` `let` is required because `$lookup` `pipeline` somehow cannot reference a previous stage field directly. note the double `$` required to reference `let` variables like `$$maxDate`
- `$project` is used because we are only interested in the amount, so the rest of the `$lookup` document needs to be discarded
- `$replaceRoot` + `$mergeObjects` + `$arrayElemAt` is used to merge the first entry in the `$lookup` result up into the root document
- the final `$project` removes the (now) unneeded `maxDate` and `latestAmount` working fields

Here's the resulting query that meets the exact specification in the question:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$category",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      maxDate: { $max: "$date" }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        category: "$_id",
        maxDate: "$maxDate"
      },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: [ "$category", "$$category" ] },
                { $eq: [ "$date", "$$maxDate" ] }
              ]
            }
        }},
        { $project: { _id: 0, amount: 1 } }
      ],
      as: "latestAmount"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          { $arrayElemAt: [ "$latestAmount", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { maxDate: 0, latestAmount: 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ktky3chzX3P)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "dateValue": {
        "$toDate": "$date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      dateValue: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$category",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "lastAmount": {
        "$last": "$amount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

In this query, we first convert the string date into a date object. This step is not required if your dates are already stored as dates. Next, we sort the documents, by date in ascending order. Finally, we group them by `category`, calculating the `count` and `last_amount`.

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o2HmGyzUp0f)

You can use this if you don't want to use sorting.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$category",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "lastAmount": {
        "$max": "$amount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UuVClMUffnu)

Comment: thanks for this. my dates are real so i guess i can skip the first op. on the sort op - i was wondering if this would get a performance hit vs some sort of max op when the collection grows to a really large number of documents? i could index the date but just wondering if there was a more efficient way to this.